Spacetime coordinates 4-dimensional vs curvature of space time?
what is the difference between spacetime coordinates 4-dimensional and curvature of space time I dont know the difference between both of them

There is a difference, although it is a rather subtle one.
Each point in spacetime (which we call an event) has a unique set of four spacetime co-ordinates. However, the values of those co-ordinates depend on the co-ordinate system that we are using.
The curvature of spacetime, however, is a physical phenomenon and is independent of our choice of co-ordinate system.
By analogy, the equation of a circle with radius $c$ in two-dimensional space will depend on the co-ordinate system that we use - in one set of Cartesian co-ordinates in will be $x^2 + y^2 = c^2$, in another it will be $x^2 + 2x + y^2 = c^2-1$, in polar co-ordinates it may be $r=c$. However, the curvature of the circle (at every point on it) is always $\frac 1 c$, no matter what co-ordinate system we use.

There is no difference. 4D spacetime coordinates are coming from that we see 3 space dimensions and 1 time dimensions. General relativity describes gravitation by that even this 4D spacetime is curved.
The "vs" in your questin is false, the curved spacetime (general relativity) is extending the first part and not contradicts it.

this cant be true as if that is true means the distance along spacetime curvature is the same as we measure with (x,y,z,ct) frame of reference but it is different as Pythagorean summation to infinity "integration" wont give us distance along curve

I can not really understand your comment. Distance over the curved space does not happen by pythagorean summation, there is a matrix formula (which results pythagorean summation in zero-curvature limit). The matrix describes the curvature of the spacetime at a specific point. ((Yet more clearly, not entirely Pythagorean summation because the time-square counts with negative signum, but that is already so in the special relativity))

In the theory of special relativity, space and time are treated as two inseparable continuum. Therefore, it doesn’t make sense to maintain the notion of describing events using spatial coordinates $(x, y, z)$, and separately the associated time $t$. Thus we use spacetime coordinates, which combines the three spatial coordinates and the one temporal coordinate into $(t, x, y, z)$. Typically the introduction of this notion is introduced in special relativity.
Curvature of spacetime refers to the way in which spacetime bends or curves in the presence of mass and energy. Such idea is introduced in general relativity. Essentially, mass and energy tell spacetime how to curve, and this curvature tells objects how to move. These concepts are formally described by Einstein’s field equations.
So the main way in which the two ways are connected is that the curvature of space time affects how the four-dimensional coordinates are interpreted, and how objects move through these coordinates.
I hope this answer helps.
